# My main.css doesn't link to my html files "outside" of my computer

Tags: html, css, tags, zip, brackets

**Im using Brackets** and I've written an index.html site with links within that lead to other .html files within the same folder. They all use the same main.css that is also within the same folder.
My problem is that when zipping it and sending it to another computer, the main.css doesn't work.

Here is my code for my index.html, the code for the other .html files looks the same.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Projekt 2</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
 </head>

<body>
 <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Förord</a></li>
    <li><a href="internet.html">Internets historia</a></li>
    <li><a href="sam.html">Samhällspåverkan</a></li>
    <li><a href="etik.html">Etik och integritet på nätet</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Every a-tag leads no another .html file in the same folder.

**Now here's the thing.**
When i preview it on Brackets, it works fine. The index.html and main.css links together. [Here's how it looks on the **Brackets preview**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yb3n.jpg)
But when i zip the folder and send it to another computer, as you they can see, the main.css suddenly doesn't work anymore, nor thus the link that are supposed to lead to the others .html files go anywhere, they just say "file can't be found" (see picture at the bottom) although they are within the same folder.

[Here's how it looks when I've zipped the folder, sent it to another computer and tried to open the index.html file. **The main.css doesn't link**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IHZ6.png)

Here is my main.css:

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
padding-top: 0px;
font-family: monospace;
background-image: url(back.jpg);
}

.nav {
background-color: dimgrey;
color: white;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
margin-top: 0px;
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out

1) Why the main.css wont link when opened on another computer

2) Why the links within the .html wont link to each other

I've searched around and can't find an answer why, I've tried changing the name and several other things, but I cant find the error. Any help is appreciated, **thanks!**

[Here's a picture of the folder on my Mac, unzipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baR1l.png)

[Picture of the same folder, but on a PC, zipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L87rO.png)

[Picture of the what comes up when trying to click on the other link within the index.html on another computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GBj4.png)

Comment: Have you tried unzipping the folder on Windows and seeing if that makes a difference?

Comment: You are trying to open the file without extracting it.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. I zipped the folder on my Mac, and sent it to myself through Gmail, dowloaded the Zip-file on my PC, and tried to opened it. Didn't work, main.css doesn't link.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is, I downloaded the zip-file, extracted it, opened the my index.html, but the css wouldn't follow.

Comment: I know that you say you have extracted the zip file before opening index.html, but the screenshot you provided (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IHZ6.png) shows .zip in the address bar which suggests the archive has not been extracted?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a `../` before your HTML file calls ex)

```
<li><a href="../index.html">Förord</a></li>
```

If that doesn't work try

```
<li><a href="(the main folder name)/index.html">Förord</a></li>
```